# Want to understand UNDX-m crossover point, "Vectors e⃗(1), ..., e⃗ (n-m) are the orthogonal basis of the subspace orthogonal to vectors d1,…,dm”

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to understand UNDX-m and stuck at this point. Does this sentence mean subspace formed by vectors e⃗(1), ..., e⃗ (n-m)  is orthogonal complement of subspace created by vectors d1,…,dm or they are orthonormal bases of subspace d1,…,dm (which I can find using gram-schmidt process)

Am I going/thinking in a right direction or completely off? Please excuse my lack of knowledge in linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what UNDX-m crossover means. But one can make a reasonable guess to the answer: the first set has $n-m$ of the $e_i$' vectors and the second set $m$ of the $d_i$  vectors.  So they are ORTHOGONAL COMPLEMENTS in an $n$-dimensional vector space. (not the second guess you have made using Gram-Schmidt)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Details about the UNDX-m can be found in [this paper](http://dynamics.org/Altenberg/UH_ICS/EC_REFS/GP_REFS/REFS_S2002/371.pdf)